# Some view to find out which jobs are in the queue to be executed?

Tags: oracle

A environment start several refreshes along the day.

[image]

If I change the `job_queue_processes` to 20 for example, it start several new jobs. Is there some view that I can see which jobs is waiting and will be executed if I change the `job_queue_processes`?

Observation: the jobs have been created with `dbms_job`.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle versions prior to 19c you can check the DBA_JOBS view for job created with the DBMS_JOBS package. For jobs created using DBMS_JOBS in Oracle 19c and later, or for jobs created with the DBMS_SCHEDULER in any version, check the DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS view.

Comment: The "queue" become the question a little confuse because Oracle calls it as queue. What I mean is which jobs are waiting some other job finish its work and then the other jobs to be able to start. In my example the job_queue_processes = 15, so the database can have just 15 jobs executing at the same time. I am sure there are some jobs waiting the current running jobs to stop and then others jobs be able to start, but I'd like to know which

Comment: There is no "queue" in that sense. Oracle will execute the jobs in the order that they were scheduled, as soon as a queue process is available. In general you should have at least as many job queue processes as you expect to have concurrent jobs, so that there is no waiting.